# Overloading the left side of insertion operator in C++

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

I haven't been able to find any references on this, mostly because of how difficult it is to search.  I'm trying to overload the extraction (<<) operator, but not in the usual way: instead, I'd like it to take the form

```
myCustomClass << data << moredata;
```

etc.  A general solution that works for any data type with a valid extraction operator would be best, since it will be passed to a valid stream in the overloaded operator function, but if necessary, limiting it to just strings is also acceptable.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @RSahu Thank you.  Does that mean that it is impossible/highly discouraged, or that I should go about it the way you wrote in that answer?

Comment: You should go about it the way I wrote in my answer.